# How to dispaly name of table from a database when match criteria

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle11g

I have the table structure as:

```
 tabble_name_temp1


    col_up      col_down

    akash      kavita 

    kavita     aruhi

    aruhi      Akash



 tabble_name_temp2


    col_up      col_down

    akash      kavita 

    kavita     simran

    jyoti     Akash


   tabble_name_temp3


    col_up      col_down

    akash      kavita 

    kavita     simran

    jyoti     Akash
```

I want select name of table having

values eg: if I enter

```
        akash and simran
```

then this should dispaly like

```
       tabble_name_temp2

       tabble_name_temp3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has `all_objects` and `all_tab_columns` tables which store table/column related data.
You can select from these tables and then form dynamic queries to check if the given data exists in these tables. Here's the sample code for a single input. If there are multiple inputs you will have to repeat this as many times.

```
DECLARE
   l_chr_query   VARCHAR2 (2000);
   l_num_count   NUMBER (1);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name, column_name
               FROM all_tab_columns
              WHERE table_name IN (
                       SELECT object_name
                         FROM all_objects
                        WHERE object_name LIKE 'SA_%' AND object_type = 'TABLE')
                AND data_type = 'VARCHAR2') --modify the where clause as per your needs
    LOOP
      l_num_count := 0;
      l_chr_query :=
            'select count(1) from ' || i.table_name || ' where ' || i.column_name
         || ' = ''akash'' and rownum = 1';

      --execute the query
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_chr_query INTO l_num_count;

      IF l_num_count > 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.table_name);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END;
```

Once a table is found, you can save it in an array and skip checking the same table in the next iteration of same table but different column.

Comment: What about the Mysql? I mean is it possible in the mysql or not?

Comment: No idea about mySQL. But i think there must be something similar in mySQL too.